# Global Numbering for Equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I have a problem opposite to most of the questions posted regarding the equation numbering. I would like to have a global numbering for equations, regardless of the section. With or without the package `chngcntr`, in the equation, it shows the global numbering, as wished.

However, when I try to refer these equation, the first one is correctly referred, but the second one includes the section number. See below for the minimal working example and the result.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,amsfonts,graphicx,subfigure,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{subsection}
\counterwithout{equation}{section} % undo numbering system provided by phstyle.cls

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\label{sec:1} 

\subsection{A} 


\subsection{B} 


\begin{align}
a &= b\notag\\
    &= c.\label{eq:a}
\end{align}

Equation (\ref{eq:a}) 
\begin{align}
a &= b
\end{align}\label{eq:b}
Equation (\ref{eq:b}) 

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to put the `\label` into the `align` environment and not out (that references the subsection).

Comment: I have posted it as answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You have one mistake in your code: The `\label` you want to tag the second equation with is outside of it. That causes LaTeX to use the subsection-counter to be referenced.

If you want to reference the equation move the `\label` into the `align` environment.